# Finding the sum of squares of the real roots

Tags: polynomials, roots

> Let $r_1,r_2,r_3,\cdots,r_n$ be the distinct real zeroes of the equation $$x^8-14x^4-8x^3-x^2+1=0.$$ Then $r_1^2+r_2^2+r_3^2+\cdots+r_n^2$ is $$(A)\,3\quad(B)\,14\quad(C)\,8\quad(D)\,16$$

I can get the sum of the squares of all roots using Vieta’s formulae, but I don't know actually how to proceed in this question.

Do I need to draw a graph and then find the answers or is there a sum trick here which I am not able to see through?

Comment: Once you get Vieta's formulae you can continue with Newton's identity, basically $a_ns_2+a_{n-1}s_1+a_{n-2}=0$. But as dxiv said, you have first to isolate the polynomial with real roots.

Answer (score 8):

Hint:   the real roots are the roots of the first factor:

$$
\begin{align}
x^8\color{red}{+2x^4-2x^4}-14x^4-8x^3-x^2+1 &= (x^4+1)^2 - x^2(4x+1)^2 \\
 &= (x^4 - 4 x^2 - x+1)(x^4+4x^2+x+1)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: but how is it guaranteed that all roots of first factor are real?

Comment: @ashishdeosingh By inspection, it is positive at $\,x=0\,$ and negative at $\,x=\pm 1\,$.

Comment: that is we using IVT. right. will it be possible for us to factorise it?

Comment: @ashishdeosingh Using IVT you can tell that there is one real root in each of $\,(-\infty, -1)\,$, $\,(-1,0)\,$, $\,(0,1)\,$, $\,(1,\infty)\,$. To actually solve/factor it you could technically use the quartic formulas to get closed forms using radicals, but the result is not pretty.

Comment: yes then thanks a lot. cant by basic manipulations be it possible?

Comment: @ashishdeosingh Short answer is no, the required manipulations are not "*basic*". Lookup the quartic formula [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots), and see the expressions calculated by Wolfram Alpha for this particular polynomial [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4+-+4+x%5E2+-+x+%2B+1+%3D+0) (click `exact forms` next to `solutions`).

Answer (score 6):

Let $$f(x)=x^8-14x^4-8x^3-x^2+1\implies f'(x)=8x^7-56x^3-24x^2-2x=0$$ for critical points. Then clearly $x=0$ is one, and is a maximum since $f''(0)<0$; $f(0)=1$.

We get $$g(x)=4x^6-28x^3-12x-1=0$$ and since $g$ is continuous, by the Mean Value Theorem, there is a minimum between $(-0.2,0)$ and a maximum between $(-0.4,-0.2)$. At these $x$, $f(x)$ is above the $x$-axis.

Hence there are at most four roots left. In a similar way, we test at $0.2$ intervals, and we find that $$f(-1.8)>0,\quad f(-1.6)<0\\f(-0.8)<0,\quad f(-0.6)>0\\f(0.2)>0,\quad f(0.4)<0\\f(2)<0,\quad f(2.2)>0.$$

Thus we have that $$(-1.6)^2+(-0.2)^2+0.2^2+2^2<r_1^2+r_2^2+r_3^2+r_4^2<(-1.8)^2+(-0.8)^2+0.4^2+2.2^2$$ or that $$6.64<r_1^2+r_2^2+r_3^2+r_4^2<8.88$$ so the only option must be $(C)$.

Comment: but this is too much of approximation and working through options. wont there be any other way to find exact ans

Comment: Yes, @dxiv has given a much neater one.

Answer (score 2):

Following the foundamental hint by dxiv, for $x^4-4x^2-x+1$ by [**Vieta's formula**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) we have

- $S_1=\sum r_i=-a_3=0$
- $S_2=\sum r_ir_j=a_2=-4$
- $S_3=\sum r_ir_jr_k=-a_1=1$
- $S_4=r_1r_2r_3r_4=a_0=1$

and by [**Newton's sums**](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Newton%27s_Sums) we have that

- $P_1=\sum r_i=S_1=0$
- $P_2=\sum r_i^2=S_1P_1-2S_2=8$

Comment: but you assuming first factor has all real roots!!!

Comment: yes that is seen. but A-B has all real roots !!how can we say that ?

Comment: second factor can be written as sum of squares so obviously no real root for it.

Comment: Yes you are right, I've overlooked that! It's a good point to clarify

Comment: @ashishdeosingh For the second factor we have that for $|x|\ge 1$ we have that $$x^4+4x^2+x+1\ge 5x^2+x+1 >0$$ and for $|x|<1$ we have $$x^4+4x^2+x+1\ge 5x^4+x+1>0$$

Comment: For the first one, as noticed, we have $p(-1)<0$, $p(0)>0$, $p(1)<0$ and therefore since $p(x)\to \infty$ as $x\to \pm \infty$ we have 4 real roots.

Comment: second factor is easy.it is x^4+ 3x^2+ (x+1/2)^2 +3/4

Comment: @ashishdeosingh Yes indeed, for the first one I can't see others method than that! it is strange that th eproblem has been given without any hint on that.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align} 
x^8-14x^4-8x^3-x^2+1&=0
\tag{1}\label{1}
.
\end{align}

\eqref{1} can be factored as

\begin{align}
f_1(x)f_2(x)=0
,\\ 
f_1(x)&=x^4+4x^2+x+1
\tag{2}\label{2}
,\\
f_2(x)&=x^4-4x^2-x+1
\tag{3}\label{3}
.
\end{align}

\begin{align}
f_1(x)&=x^4+3x^2+(x^2+x+\frac14)-\tfrac14+1
\\
&=x^4+3x^2+\tfrac14(2x+1)^2+\tfrac34
>0\quad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}
.
\end{align}

We can also found that 
factor $f_2(x)$ has four distinct real roots,
for example, observing that

\begin{align}
f_2(-2)&=3>0
,\\
f_2(-1)&=-1<0
,\\
f_2(0)&=1>0
,\\
f_2(1)&=-3<0
,\\
f_2(3)&=43>0
,
\end{align}

Now consider 
\begin{align}
f_2(x)f_2(-x)&=
(x^2)^4-8(x^2)^3+18(x^2)^2-9(x^2)+1
\tag{4}\label{4}
.
\end{align}

Expression \eqref{3}
is a polynomial in $x^2$,
its roots are squares of the roots of\eqref{1},
hence the sought sum 
of the squares of distinct real roots of  \eqref{1}
is $8$ (negated coefficient at $(x^2)^3$ in \eqref{4}).